# Example of a continuous function constant on some subset

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Question is to give an example of a continuous function $f:[-1,1]\times[-1,1]\rightarrow\{0\}\times [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ such that $f(a)=a$ for all $a\in\{0\}\times [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] $..

Any element in $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ is of the form $t(-1,m)+(1-t)(1,m)$ for some $t\in [0,1]$ and $-1\leq m\leq 1$...

Suppose the range is $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ I would have considered the function that is constant for each $m$..

I mean i would define $f(t(-1,m)+(1-t)(1,m))=(0,m)$ then it is clealy continuous and $f(a)=a$ for all $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$..

I am not very sure how to define if range is $\{0\}\times [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] $..

Please give only hints..

Comment: What about $f(a,b) = (0 , g(b) )$ where, $g$ is a continuous function and for $-\frac{1}{2}<b<\frac{1}{2}$ we have $g(b) = b$?

Comment: Ok... How do you get such $g$?

Comment: $g(b)$ is a function s.t. for $-1<b<0.5$, $g(b) = -1 - b$,  $-0.5<b<0.5$, $g(b) =b$, and for  $0.5<b<1$, $g(b) = 1 - b$

Comment: How about $g(x)=-\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\leq -\frac{1}{2}$ , $=x$ for $x\in[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$... identity function and extend constantly on two sides @corbah

Comment: That works as well.

Comment: @corbah : Thanks, that helped a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g:\left[-1,1\right]^{2}\to\left\{ 0\right\} \times\left[-1,1\right]$
be prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle0,y\rangle$.

Let $h:\left\{ 0\right\} \times\left[-1,1\right]\to\left\{ 0\right\} \times\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$
be prescribed by $\langle0,y\rangle\mapsto\langle0,\frac{1}{2}\rangle$
if $y\geq\frac{1}{2}$, $\langle0,y\rangle\mapsto\langle0,-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$
if $y\leq-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\langle0,y\rangle\mapsto\langle0,y\rangle$
otherwise.

Then $g$ and $h$ are both continuous, so that $f:=h\circ g$ is
continuous.

This with $f\left(0,b\right)=\langle0,b\rangle$ if $b\in\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

Comment: Sir, I have written same $h$ just now :)

Comment: @cello Indeed. If you write it as an answer then I will upvote.

Comment: I  am happy that i got same example as you got... No upvote is necessary :) :)